# Emirates trans-Tasman additional luggage costs?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, emirates

Trying to find a weird use case for Emirates.

If you have a 1st class ticket, you're allowed 50kg for a flight from SYD to AKL/WLG/CHC.

However, I can't find out how much additional luggage would cost trans-Tasman if you've purchased a 1st class ticket.

Weight limits seem to be here: https://www.emirates.com/au/english/before-you-fly/baggage/checked-baggage.aspx but I can't find costs.

Eg an extra $$xx per yyy kg?

Comment: https://www.emirates.com/au/english/before-you-fly/baggage/purchase-additional-baggage-allowance.aspx

Comment: 50 kg are already a lot. You may consider to send it as cargo (which is often cheaper) if you have some extra flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emirates posts and updates extra luggage costs on [this webpage](https://www.emirates.com/au/english/before-you-fly/baggage/purchase-additional-baggage-allowance.aspx). As of today, the cost of extra luggage on flights departing from Australia to New Zealand are 15$ per kg regardless of flight class:

[image: Emirates cost for additional baggage]

Note that it is cheaper to purchase extra luggage online than at the airport:

> #### Purchasing online
>
> Where the baggage allowance on your ticket is based on weight, you can purchase additional baggage online, at discounted rates, in blocks of 5kg up to a maximum of 25kg.
>
> Online discounts per passenger are:
>
> - 50% for the first 5kg;
> - 20% for any subsequent amount.